# IIS Group Access

Tags: iis-7

I'm running an Intranet and would like to restrict access to the site to only a specific group on active directory.

I've turned off anonymous authentication and have windows authentication and basic authentication turned on.

I've added the specific user group to the security group to give them permission to view the site. I've also removed the servername\users group to prevent users without privileges accessing the site.

When I do this the site will not load and I get a 500 server error. If I re-add the users group the site works but allows users outside the specific group access to the site.

How can I set this up correctly?

Any advice would be great.

Jemes

IIS7, Windows Server 2008